# How do I get the user who invoked a SQL Agent job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a job step which needs to reference the Login Name value for the user who started the job. It'll be passed as a value into a table field, which is then referenced by other processes.

I haven't been able to find if or where the starting username is stored in system tables. It must be stored *somewhere* as the (job outcome) step in `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` references is thusly:

```
The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by User [domain]\[username].  The last step to run was...
```

I'd like to capture that `[domain]\[username]` value for my job step. I know it can be done as a subsequent job, referencing the original and doing some string manipulation, but I'd prefer to do it in the same job, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That is logged in the `message` column of the `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` table.

You may want to do some joins to the sysjobs table as well. I.E.

```
select 
    j.name as 'JobName',
    run_date,
    run_time,
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) as 'RunDateTime',
    case 
        when left(h.message,16) = 'Executed as user' 
            then substring(h.message,19,charindex('.',h.message,1) - 18)
        when h.message like '%invoked by%'
            then substring(h.message,charindex('invoked by ',h.message) + 11,charindex('.',substring(h.message,charindex('invoked by ',h.message) + 11,99)) - 1)
        else h.message
    end
From 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
    ON j.job_id = h.job_id 
where 
    j.enabled = 1  --Only Enabled Jobs
order by 
    JobName, 
    RunDateTime desc
```

[REF](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/)

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response, but I need the user who invoked the job *before* it finishes. The only time the invoking user is referenced appears to be in the final step in `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory`, which is too late for my purposes.

Comment: well for that case you'd have to look at open connections with sp_who2 'Active' or sp_whoIsActive by [Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2016/10/18/sp-whoisactive-the-big-fixes.aspx)